# ASP.NET Core: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime 0:dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: asp.net, date

I'm trying to manually set a string as a valid DateTime in the following model:

```
namespace Application.Models
{
    public class Tienda
    {
    ...
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime tienda_fecha_fin { get; set; }
    ...
```

Thru the Controller:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int? id, StoreIndexData AddStore)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             var store = new Tienda();
             store.tienda_fecha_fin = DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/9999 12:00:00", "0:dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I've tried different ways since I can't remember what is the exact format `0:dd/MM/yyyy` is expecting.

I've tried:

31/12/9999;
31/12/9999 12:00:00 AM;
31/12/9999 12:00:00

With no luck so far

Answer (score 2):

**You are trying to parse "31/12/9999 12:00:00" to "dd/MM/yyyy"**

You should use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/9999", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/9999 12:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `0:` portion of the format argument when calling DateTime.ParseExact.  That is a placeholder used within a string template when calling the `string.Format` method.

You want:
`DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/9999", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`